# Can't connect to Snowflake with newly created Airflow environment on EC2

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow-scheduler

I have an AWS Cloudformation template that creates a basic airflow environment (one EC2 t3.small instance hosts both the webserver and scheduler, no external DB, no celery executor). This environment connects to a Snowflake data warehouse to push files from S3 into the databases on Snowflake. I successfully create an airflow environment on my EC2 instance, and the very last thing I do in the CFT is to activate the airflow scheduler. Logs seem to indicate a clean start and the webserver starts with no problem. when running a test DAG to just connect to Snowflake, I get this error:

```
[2020-02-11 11:23:25,422] {__init__.py:1580} ERROR - 250001 (08001): None: Failed to connect to DB: xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443. IP [69995088867598] is not allowed to access Snowflake.  Contact your local security administrator.
```

Here is what we know:

1) The IP address coming from EC2 is fine, it is not blacklisted or not on a whitelist on the Snowflake side, so this error is a little puzzling.

2) Manually running a Python script outside of Airflow works fine - connection to Snowflake happens as expected.

3) Killing the Airflow scheduler, starting it back up via 'airflow scheduler -D', and then re-running the DAG will result in a successful run.

4) The logs don't indicate any other errors other than what I posted above.

Here is the userdata portion of my CFT:

```
    'Fn::Base64':
      !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash -x
      exec > /tmp/user-data.log 2>&1

      # Path settings
      export HOME=/root
      export AIRFLOW_HOME=$HOME/airflow
      export PATH=$PATH:/root/airflow:/root/airflow/bin

      # Egress proxy and exceptions

      # Step 1: Install Python version
      apt-get update -y
      apt-get install build-essential checkinstall -y
      apt-get install libssl-dev openssl zlib1g-dev libffi-dev libsqlite3-dev libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-client python3-psycopg2 -y
      wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tgz
      tar xzvf Python-3.7.3.tgz
      cd Python-3.7.3
      ./configure
      make
      make altinstall

      # Step 2: Create virtual environment with new Python version
      cd ~
      python3.7 -m venv airflow

      # Create pip.conf
      echo '[global]
      proxy = http://http.proxy.com:8000
      index-url = https://${ArtifactoryUsername}:${ArtifactoryPassword}@artifactory.com/api/pypi/pypi-prereleases/simple
      index = https://${ArtifactoryUsername}:${ArtifactoryPassword}@artifactory.com/api/pypi/pypi-prereleases/simple' > $AIRFLOW_HOME/pip.conf

      # Allow these ports through the ufw firewall
      sudo ufw allow 8080

      # Upgrade Pip
      $AIRFLOW_HOME/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
      /usr/local/bin/aws s3 sync s3://${S3CDAPBucket}/dags $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags/

      # Install required PIP packages into virtual environment
      $AIRFLOW_HOME/bin/pip install -r $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags/requirements.txt --no-cache-dir --retries 10

      # Setup airflow local db; edit config file as needed
      $AIRFLOW_HOME/bin/airflow initdb
      sed -i 's/load_examples\s=\sTrue/load_examples = False/g' $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg
      sed -i 's/default_dag_run_display_number\s=\s25/default_dag_run_display_number = 5/g' $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg
      sed -i "/remote_logging\s=\sFalse/c\remote_logging = True" $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg
      sed -i "/remote_base_log_folder\s=/c\remote_base_log_folder = s3://${S3CDAPBucket}/logs" $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg

      # Re-init the database to use the postgres instance; start scheduler and webserver
      $AIRFLOW_HOME/bin/airflow pool -i $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags/config/airflow/airflow-pool-config.json
      sed -i "/snowflake_batch_password/c\   \"snowflake_batch_password\" : \"${SnowflakeBatchPassword}\"," $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags/config/airflow/airflow-variables-dev.json

      $AIRFLOW_HOME/bin/airflow variables -i $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags/config/airflow/airflow-variables-dev.json

      sudo apt autoremove -y
      chgrp -R cloud-user /root
      chmod -R g+rwx /root
      $AIRFLOW_HOME/bin/airflow webserver -D
      $AIRFLOW_HOME/bin/airflow scheduler -D
```

The DAG testing connection to snowflake looks like this:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json
import os
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow import AirflowException
from snowflake import snowflake_hook
from aws.s3 import FileOps
import boto3
from dag_admin import common_dag_tasks, landing_zone_dag_tasks, raw_zone_dag_tasks
from logger import logger
from functools import partial
import traceback
from data_validation import batch_validation
from snowflake.snowflake_hook import SnowflakeHook

def snowflake_task():
    my_snowflake = SnowflakeHook(account='xxxxxxxxxxx.us-east-1',
                                            username='SNOWFLAKE_DEV_BATCH_USER',
                                            password='password',
                                            warehouse='DEV_BATCH_XSMALL',
                                            role='DEV_DB_DEVELOPER_ROLE')
    conn = my_snowflake.get_conn()
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
            cur.execute('select count(*) as row_cnt from DEV.LANDING__MST_DC_DBO.DC_ACCOUNTING_ITEM__BULK')
            for (row_cnt) in cur:
                print('Row Count = {}'.format(row_cnt))
    finally:
            cur.close()

    conn.close()


dag_id = 'snowflake-test'
my_dag = DAG(dag_id=dag_id,
             start_date=datetime.today(),
             schedule_interval=None)

start_task = PythonOperator(
                        task_id="start-task",
                        dag=my_dag,
                        python_callable=snowflake_task)
```

Requirements.txt:

```
apache-airflow==1.10.3
Jinja2==2.10.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
tzlocal==1.5.1
Flask==1.0.4
snowflake-connector-python==2.0.3
inhouse-snowflake==1.0.0
marshmallow-sqlalchemy==0.17.1
inhouse-aws==1.0.0
inhouse-dag-admin==1.0.0
psycopg2==2.8.4
boto3==1.9.253
inhouse-logging==1.0.0
inhouse-data-validation==1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error seems that you might have a Network policy enable in your Snowflake account. 
You need to get the public IP of your EC2 machine and add it to your allowed IPs.

[Here](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/network-policies.html#managing-account-level-network-policies) the full tutorial. Also, you need to consider to use an Elastic-IP and attach to your machine, in this way the public IP won't change, even if your machine is terminated, you can still attach the publicIP.

Comment: I can connect to Snowflake just fine on an EC2 instance with a Python (non-Airflow) script, and if I kill the Airflow scheduler on EC2 and restart it, the DAG connects fine. If it were a network whitelist/blacklist issue, I don't think it would be remedied by an Airflow scheduler restart.

Comment: All right, but your error message it's exactly the same that some of our users get when they try to connect from a blacklisted IP. https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/Getting-error here the same error that you getting, and they pointed out that is Network policy issue.

Comment: @BPS forget what I said, I just read your full issue. Can you put a retry in your Airflow task to see if at the second attempt works? The airflow scheduler has nothing to do with executing the task itself.

Comment: No idea why this is happing, it quite weird indeed.

Comment: Silly question: is the NAT IP whitelisted (is this the same as the public ip?) and second silly question: is the dev role managed by the network policy, do you get the same error when you change the role to accountadmin?